# Conditional statement is not working in if condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am using a dynamic script which create conditions dynamically like

```
$condition_string =  '1==0 AND 1==1';
```

When I try to use variable in `if` condition, it does not work.

```
if($condition_string) {

  // do something

}
```

However, if I use

```
if(1==0 AND 1==1) {

  // do something

}
```

then it works.

Can somebody tell how to use variable in condition ?

Comment: What's $rule_condition_string ?

Comment: sorry it is $condition_string.

Comment: I have also tried && in condition.. but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @M.Page: You can use both `&&` or `AND` (with slightly different [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)) in PHP.

Comment: Variables do not work like copy and pasting code. `if ($string)` evaluates whether the `$string` equals `true` according to PHP's rules, which pretty much means any non-empty string is regarded as `true`. It does not read the string's contents and evaluate them as PHP code, and that's a good thing.

Comment: I don't know why there is a difference between using $variable and direct numbers in condition statement.

Comment: @Nisse Engström, yes sure 100% right, but I wrote this in the context of the OP question.

Comment: Perhaps if you want to use as 'AND' as a condition use str_replace with the conditions AND, OR and NOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the eval function to build and evaluate dynamic script, so:

```
 eval("if($condition_string){ /*do here what you need*/ }else{ /*...*/}");
```

would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $condition_string =  '1==0 AND 1==1';
>
> if($condition_string) {
>   // do something
> }
> ```

The condition in an `if` statement will be [converted to `boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) before it is evaluated. A string will be evaluated as `TRUE` unless it is an empty string or the string `"0"`. Therefore, your condition above will always be true.

One option is to use `eval` to evaluate the condition outside of the `if`:

```
eval ('$condition_string = (1==0 OR 1==1);');

if($condition_string) {
  // do something
}
```

Note that `AND` has *lower* [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the `=` operator, so you must use parenthesis around the expression. This is not necessary if you use the `&&` operator, which has *higher* precedence than `=`.

Note also the warning in the [`eval` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> **Caution**
>
> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a function that uses `eval`, but please note this which is stated in the [PHP manual for eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> Caution
> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

```
function eval_str($string) {
    return eval("return $string;");
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
$condition_string = '1==0 AND 1==1';
if(eval_str($rule_condition_string)) { // false
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach although it's a bit more involved.  However, it avoids using eval, as follows:

```
<?php
$condition_string =  '1==0 || 1==1';
$arr = preg_split("/[ ==||]+/",$condition_string );
$callback = function( $s ){
    return (int) $s;
};
$arrNums = array_map( $callback,$arr );
list( $n1, $n2, $n3, $n4 ) = $arrNums;
if (($n1 == $n2 ) || ( $n3 == $n4 )) {
    echo "result of logical ||: this works\n";
}
// result of logical ||: this works
```

preg_split searches for whether the string contains a space, ==, or ||. If so the string gets split into an array of strings containing only the numbers.  Arrap_map creates a new array that contains the integers corresponding to each numerical string in $arr.  $arrNums gets split into a list which contains variables which take on its values.  The if conditional compares each pair of numbers for equality.  Since the code uses the logical || operator, when the second pair of numbers evaluates as true, the conditional evaluates as true, too, with the net result of the outputted confirmation string.